# Why is there a bulge at the top of my volumetric flask?

Tags: equipment

Sometimes volumetric flasks are designed with a bulge in the neck right below the stopper opening. What is the design intent of that bulge?

[image]

Comment: I'd assume just an artifact of joining the ground glass joint to the neck of the flask.

Comment: It's also there to help you grip better. This way there's a stop if it starts to slide in your hand.

Answer (score 17):

From *ASTM manual* [1, p. 204], emphasis mine:

> Volumetric flasks should be diluted to just below the line, mixed thoroughly, then allowed to stand for 4 to 24 h to allow any heat from an acid-water reaction to dissipate. [...] Thorough mixing consists of at least 20 complete inversions of the volumetric flask, allowing enough time on each for the air bubble to completely traverse the length of the vessel. **Some borosilicate volumetric flasks contain a bulge in the neck above the line as an aid to proper mixing**.

[Volumetric pipetts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_pipette) also have a large bulge in the middle, but it serves a different purpose – to keep the $\rm length : volume$ ratio minimal and still maintain quick liquid collection with high precision.

#### Reference

1. Dulski, T. R. A Manual for the Chemical Analysis of Metals; ASTM manual series; *ASTM: West Conshohocken, PA*, **1996**. ISBN 978-0-8031-2066-2.